# Unwanted empty strings when reading input from stdio

Tags: d

Just making exercise with simple calculator. I've tried to run ahead and wraped it inside do-while loop. Then I've got a strange behaviour - catchin empty string on every new loop. One can see that at `case ""` code part.

So the question - what is going on and how to deal with it?

One can see my humble attempts to fix it on commented lines in the code:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.string;

void main() {

    writefln("---  Welcome to calculatro %s ---", " ");

    int exit = 0;

    do {


        string op;
        double first;
        double second;

        writeln("enter operator :");
        op = chomp(readln());
        writeln("operator :",op,":");
        //readf(" %s/n", &op);


        switch (op) {

        case "add", "+":
            writeln("enter two values :");
            //readf(" %s %s", &first, &second);
            readf(" %s", &first);
            readf(" %s", &second);
            writefln("%s+%s=%s", first, second, first+second);
            //writeln(first+second);   
            break;

        case "minus", "-", "substract":      
            writeln("enter two values :");
            readf(" %s %s", &first, &second);
            writefln("%s+%s=%s", first, second, first-second);
            break;        

        case "exit":
            exit = 1;
            break;

        case "":
            writeln("empty op");
            break;

        default:
            writefln("i dont know op!"~op);
            //writefln("%(%s%)", op);
            //writefln("%s", op);
            //throw new Exception(format("Unknown operation: %s", op));
            break;
        }    
    } while (exit == 0);

        writeln("good bye!");

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider a run of 'calculatro':

```
---  Welcome to calculatro   ---
enter operator :
+
operator :+:
enter two values :
4 5
4+5=9
enter operator :
operator ::
empty op
enter operator :
```

1. The user enters an operator, leaving '+\n' on stdio
2. You use `readln` to consume all of stdio
3. The user enters '4 5\n' as operands
4. You use `readf` to consume '4 5', **leaving '\n' on stdio**
5. The next loop, `readln` reads the next line from stdio
6. There is already a line on stdio, consisting only of the '\n' left from before
7. Because `readln` was able to read a whole line, the user is not prompted from input
8. `chomp` removes the '\n', leaving you with an empty string

A quick fix here is to call `readln` after you get your operands to consume the trailing newline. For example:

```
    case "add", "+":
        writeln("enter two values :");
        //readf(" %s %s", &first, &second);
        readf(" %s", &first);
        readf(" %s", &second);
        readln(); // <----- read trailing newline
        writefln("%s+%s=%s", first, second, first+second);
        //writeln(first+second);   
        break;
```